# SQLite (PCL) query in Windows XAML not allowing more than 21 columns?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, nullreferenceexception

I've used [SQLite-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/3.8.2) in my Universal Windows 8.1 RunTime app. 
There's a big table with **23 columns** in my project. The problem is - though table-creation & data-insertion codes run without any error, but in the full-column query `(SELECT * FROM table)` is not giving me more than 21 columns.

Here's my create-table method (it runs OK):

```
    private void CreateTable()
    {
        string CREATE_TABLE_SQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " // 0
                + KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TEXT, "        // 1
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT, "        // 2

            // ... all other column names are stated here in the similar way

                + KEY_LAST_EDITED_BY + " INTEGER, " // 20
                + KEY_LAST_EDIT_TIME + " TEXT, "    // 21
                + KEY_IS_LD + " INTEGER "        // 22
                + ");";
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DB_NAME))
        {
            using (var statement = connection.Prepare(CREATE_TABLE_SQL))
            {
                statement.Step();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my row-insertion SQL query (it runs OK too):

```
string insQuery = 
       @"INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME
          + " ( " + KEY_ID + ", " //1
          + KEY_UPDATED_AT + ", "//2
          + KEY_CREATED_AT + " , "//3
          // all other col. names are stated here
          + KEY_LAST_EDITED_BY + ", "//21
          + KEY_LAST_EDIT_TIME + ", "//22
          + KEY_IS_LD + " "//23
          + " ) " 
          + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

But if I query all the rows or a specific row with all columns, the prepared statement can't go beyond index 20, hence I'm assuming it's not containing more than 21 columns inside it.
Here's the code which doesn't run OK & gives NullReferenceException during access of 21th item:

```
public List<MyModel> GetAll()
{
    List<MyModel> objList = new List<MyModel>();

    string query = @"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                        + " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC;";
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DB_NAME))
    {
        using (var statement = connection.Prepare(query))
        {
            // The next line prints this: "Statement data-count=0, ColumnCount=23"
            ALog.d("Statement data-count=" + statement.DataCount + 
                    ", ColumnCount=" + statement.ColumnCount); 
            while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                try
                {
                    int id = Int32.Parse(statement[0].ToString());
                    string updatedAt = statement[1].ToString();
                    string createdAt = statement[2].ToString();
                    // ... all other values are extracted here, then I'm building
                    //  my user object & the next line prints my expected values
                    ALog.d("User: " + user.ToString());

                    // ... the remaining columns are got here nicely
                    string imgUrl = statement[19].ToString();
                    int lastEdt = Int32.Parse(statement[20].ToString());

                    // This line is the culprit giving out NullReferenceException >_<
                    string lastEdtTm = statement[21].ToString();
                    bool isLd = Int32.Parse(statement[22].ToString()) > 0;

                    objList.Add(new MyModel(
                        // Params. of the constructor goes here ...
                     ));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ALog.d("Db - GetAll() : Exception:: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }

            // This line prints as: "Statement data-count=23, ColumnCount=23"
            // That means - all my data & columns have been queried,
            // but I couldn't read values from statement[21] & statement[22]
                ALog.d("Statement data-count=" + statement.DataCount + 
                        ", ColumnCount=" + statement.ColumnCount);
                statement.Reset();
                statement.ClearBindings();
        }
    }

    return objList;
}
```

Please note that, I've more than 10 tables in the project with less than 17 columns & all of those are working fine.

Comment: Have you checked that `statement[21]` does not in fact contain a `null` value? Since your calling `.ToString()` on it, that might cause problems. Also, have you tried fetching a smaller number of columns, but starting from e.g. col 21? (I'd just like to clarify if the problem might be related to the number of columns, or to a specific column...)

Comment: Yep - checked it to be null ... but that is exactly my question: Why this has to be null?

Comment: @Kjartan Good point ... let me try to fetch the specific column.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant - I mean check whether the returned value is `null`. If it is, you ought to replace `statement[21].ToString()` with `statement[21] == null ? "" : statement[21].ToString()`. That will return an empty string if the value was null (actually, you can do that anyway).

Comment: That's it :) ... I just had the specific column(21st) value null & it has been null for all the rows in the table.
So, it turns out that there's no such column-number restrictions as I assumed at first.
Thanks @Kjartan ... Please put your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: Glad to help! :) Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to lines like this:

```
string lastEdtTm = statement[21].ToString();
```

Here, if `statement[21]` returns a `null` value, then that is equivalent to `null.ToString()`, which will throw an exception.

Easy fix:

```
string lastEdtTm = statement[21] == null ? "" : statement[21].ToString();
```

This will return an empty string if `statement[21]` resolves to `null`, or it`s string value otherwise.

Note that you should do this for *all columns that may potentially return null* - just because you're not getting that exception other places right now, does not mean you might not get it later when new rows are added, which may be missing other values.